# Chess puzzle with bishops and pawns

Tags: chess

[image: Board setup]

[FEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation): B7/2pp4/8/PP2p3/K7/8/5k1b/8 w - - 0 1

The board contains only bishops, pawns, and kings. You're playing White, and it's your turn. How quickly can you force a mate, despite the material disadvantage?

<sub><sub>Source: Valentin Rudenko, 2.hm Achalgazdra Kommunisti,
1956.</sub></sub>

Comment: This is a tough situation, so long as black doesn't move their king to a white square, this'll end up being a stalemate. I'm sure there's a way to do it, but it's not immediately obvious to me. +1

Comment: Great puzzle! $(+1)$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the key is

> To promote your pawn to a Queen first, and control the A8-H1 diagonal with the Q-B combo, as @PerpetualJ has mentioned.

The sequence of moves would probably start with

> 1. a6! (push the pawn) Bf4 (mobilize the Black bishop). We then need to block the black square diagonal g1-a7, since this is the best diagonal for Black to block the coronation with 2...Be3 next. Then we use a pawn to achieve this, using 2. b6. 2. ... cxb6 is then forced, otherwise 3. b7 crowns the pawn. Then 3. Kb5!! blocks the Black bishop from accessing a7. Black rushes the pawn with 3...e4 4. a7 e3. White needs to control the diagonal as we mentioned, they do this with 5. Bh1. Black keeps rushing with 5...e2 6. a8=Q e1=Q. Unfortunately it’s now too late for Black, because the Queen serves as a barrier for the Black King now! 7. Qf3+ forces 7...Kg1, and then the final blow is delivered with 8. Qg2#.

So I think the answer is

> Mate in 8 (lol, it rhymes!)

Notice that

> The first Black move 1...Bf4 with the intended 2...Be3 is necessary; moving the two pawns out of the way instead loses because 1. a6 c5? 2. a7 e4? 3. Bh1 creates an unstoppable a-pawn. 1...Bg1 has some merit, but ultimately fails because the Black king has to move out of the way; Ke3, Ke2, and Ke1 block the e-pawn; and Kf1 has the same effect as above except blocks the king in faster with 7. Qg2#.

Comment: Move 2 is the key, I couldn't figure how to prevent what you prevented, then I finally did but you'd already posted.

Comment: What if black plays 6... e1=N?

Comment: I think that's it. Haven't checked all the moves in detail, but this looks like the solution I had.

Comment: @Randal'Thor isaacg has a point: why black would trap themselves by promoting to a queen?

Comment: 6...e1=N leads to a massive material disadvantage, which only really delays the inevitable (Q + B vs. N + B). It is true that this delays the mate in 2 of 6...e1=Q, but the White Queen will be able to eventually trap the Black King regardless. It’s a losing situation either way.

Comment: @El-Guest The inevitable checkmate is not a reason to make a blunder. No sane chess player would consider the massive advantage of a queen over a knight, if that leads them to an obvious mate, especially if that knight prevents a check on the next turn. Either that promotion shouldn't be to a queen, or it should be deferred. Maybe this indicates that this is not exactly the right solution (I upvoted it nonetheless) and the white should somehow prevent the pawn promotion from happening.

Comment: @xhienne that’s fair, but in the case of 6...e1=N there is no tidy solution — you’re going to end up with a mate in 30-40 moves in such a case. This seems to be a situation taken from a game, instead of a created problem though based on Rand’s title — maybe the author’s opponent originally played suboptimally.

Comment: @El-Guest Rudenko being an [international grandmaster for chess composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_grandmasters_for_chess_composition), I guess this is not a situation that actually occurred. If you end up with a mate in 30-40 moves, then I suspect something is missing in your solution so that the end is shorter and non-ambiguous.

Comment: @xhienne for the sake of uncovering what happened, I searched up whether this puzzle was available online. The solution that Chess.com provides is [here](https://www.chess.com/forum/view/daily-puzzles/8-17-2018-v-rudenko-achalgazdra-kommunisti-1956) although I’ve not found anything further. I agree though that this seems not as well posed as others I’ve solved.

Comment: I believe you are right. Given that [endgame study](https://chesscafe.com/endgame-studies/endgame-study-913/)'s conclusion ("The composer does not seem to have taken 6…e1N into account, though it is still a win for White") I think your answer should be accepted.

Comment: That’s a great find, @xhienne — I’m glad that we two are not alone in this conclusion. At any rate, if you’re interested in playing a daily game or two, send me a private message — I have an account on Chess.com!

Comment: @xhienne fair enough, I’m glad that you enjoyed the puzzle at least! Was a pleasure solving this with you.

Answer (score 3):

I would personally go on the assault to take other pieces.

> Lead with your king, though you can't check with the king, you can take the pawns. You'll need to lure the black bishop and pawns into the **h1-8** diagonal. So long as you're able to retain your pieces, the black king will eventually have no defense and will be forced to surrender or stalemate will eventually happen.

Comment: It would have been funny if you could make a **perpetual** check occur, hahah :P